# Ohm symbol shows in gnuplot wxt window, exported SVG from the window, but not in SVG term output

Tags: svg, gnuplot

I have a sequence of gnuplot commands that produces a label with an underscript _{1} and the Ω symbol {/Symbol W} preceded by a small space &{.}, which

- show correctly in the wxt window
- show correctly on a  SVG file exported from the wxt window
- shows no underscript and .W if plotted to the SVG terminal

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
set label 3 "R_{1} 100&{.}{/Symbol W}"
set terminal svg size 1024,768 dynamic font 'Lohit' fsize 14 enhanced background 'white'
set output 'svg-file.svg'
plot ...
set terminal wxt 0 font 'Lohit,14' enhanced
set output
plot ...
```

I set both terminal to enhanced mode. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better these days to input Unicode directly, rather than using the Symbol font. Ω!

Comment: That works for &Omega;, and may work _{1} but things like _{min} won't as Unicode subscript does not include all chars and it's recommended to use a markup language. I'll take this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your example with gnuplot's svg terminal contains the label as

```
<tspan font-family="Symbol" >W</tspan>
```

which leaves it to the viewer/browser to display it correctly. Your example works fine for me with Chrome/Edge, but not with Firefox.

The output of the wxt-svg-export doesn't contain text like show above, but the text is converted to paths in order to avoid such platform and viewer dependency (but has other drawbacks)

Comment: I  looked at the generated SVG and my expectation was for svg terminal and wxt-svg-export to generate the same, and thus the thought I had an omission on my set terminal commands.  Guess they don't.

Comment: The svg output is directly generated by the gnuplot terminal, whereas the svg export from wxt is done by libcairo.